# pytest plugin: Can I resolve fixture functions during test collection?

Tags: pytest

I'm attempting to write a pytest plugin to validate the type of fixture functions against the annotations given in the test, similar to [pytest-fixture-typecheck](https://github.com/untitaker/pytest-fixture-typecheck).  For example:

```
@pytest.fixture
def foo() -> float:
    return 0.0


def test_foo(foo: int) -> None:
    """ This test should fail because foo is annotated as an int, but the fixture returns a float.
    """
```

However, pytest-fixture-typecheck validates the runtime type of the fixture value against the annotation when the test itself runs.  Instead I would like to:

1. Validate the annotation in the test parameter against the annotated type of the fixture function.
2. Perform this check during test collection.

This is because in my test environment, test setup is potentially slow and costly (e.g. due to using cloud resources).  So ideally I would like to create a simple check that can run stand-alone without needing the real environment.

**So, my question is, is there a way I can safely and correctly resolve fixtures at test collection time?**  For example, in `pytest_itemcollected`.  Getting the names of fixtures and the type annotations from the test seems tractable, so I just need access to the fixture function object so I can access the annotation there.  I'm also assuming that once I have the types I can use [typeguard](https://pypi.org/project/typeguard/) or similar to check that the types are compatible.

I'm open to alternative suggestions.  E.g. would I be better off trying to teach mypy about fixture resolution?

Comment: I don't have a good answer here, but I think trying to teach mypy about fixtures would be the preferred option. IDEs like PyCharm already do that (e.g. know about fixtures while type-checking). Note that there is a [related discussion](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/5981) in pytest.